# 'Sidebar' between two columns

Tags: memoir, sidebar

Can I put `\sidebar` in between two columns?

(`\sidebar` is in the `Memoir` class.)

UPDATE:
As requested in the comments, here is an MWE. Tested with PDFLaTeX on MikTeX on Windows.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\somefill}{One two three four five 6 7 8 9 10.}
\newcommand{\alsofill}{\somefill \somefill \somefill \somefill
No useful info here. \somefill \somefill \somefill \somefill \somefill}

\setlength\columnsep{3cm}
\setlength\sidebarwidth{2.5cm}
\setlength\sidebartopsep{0.85cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\somefill]
\alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}

\alsofill \sidebar{\somefill}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```